# Loop through a list of tickers with separate outputs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I have a list of tickers of which I would like to output individual datasets with financial information from pandas datareader.

I have tried to create a simple loop that takes a list of tickers and inputs it into the pandas datareader function.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
myTickers = ['AAPL', 'PG']

for ticks in myTickers:
    print(ticks)
    ticks = pdr.DataReader(ticks, 'yahoo', start='2019-01-01', end='2019-01-08')['Adj Close']
```

The problem here seems to be that the loop only substitutes in the myTickers values inside the DataReader function but it does not change the name of the dataframe from "ticks" to e.g. AAPL. Thereby all results will be overridden with whatever ticker loops last.

What do I need to modify in order for this loop to output two different dataframes with the names in the ticker list?

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the loop variable is forgotten, so needs to be stored somewhere. You could replace `ticks` in `myTickers` with it's corresponding DataFrame. However, a reference to the ticker will be useful. Perhaps the following may help.

---

```
tickers_df_dict = {
     ticks: pdr.DataReader(ticks, 'yahoo', start='2019-01-01', end='2019-01-08')['Adj Close'] 
     for ticks in myTickers
}
```

That being said, as far as I'm aware, using the yahoo API will result in the following error. You may need to revise your chosen data source.

---

> **ImmediateDeprecationError**: 
>   Yahoo Daily has been immediately deprecated due to large breaks in the API without the
>   introduction of a stable replacement. Pull Requests to re-enable these data
>   connectors are welcome.
>
> See https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues

Comment: Thank you. This almost gets me to what I want, but I would still have to split out the dictionary through for example pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tickers_df_dict['AAPL']).

Comment: The `dict` values are `pd.DataFrame` objects, so you can simply use `tickers_df_dict['AAPL']`. `pdr.DataReader(ticks, 'yahoo', start='2019-01-01', end='2019-01-08') ` returns a `pd.DataFrame` object

Answer (score 0):

You can save in a DataFrame, after get a col like a dataframe with a function.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
myTickers = ['AAPL', 'PG']
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=myTickers)

for ticks in myTickers:
    df[ticks] = pdr.DataReader(ticks, 'yahoo', start='2019-01-01', end='2019-01-08')['Adj Close']

def ticks(s):
        return df[s].to_frame()
```

---

```
ticks('AAPL')
```

> Output:

```
            AAPL
Date    
2019-01-02  156.049484
2019-01-03  140.505798
2019-01-04  146.503891
2019-01-07  146.177811
2019-01-08  148.964386
```

---

```
ticks('PG')
```

> Output:

```
            PG
Date    
2019-01-02  89.350105
2019-01-03  88.723633
2019-01-04  90.534523
2019-01-07  90.172348
2019-01-08  90.505157
```

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for a piece of logic that is able to output into two separate sets of data.